# Referencing image asset in winui 3 library

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, winui-3

I created a winui 3 library (Project A) were I included an Assets folder were I added an image called logo-256.png and a control (mycontrol) referencing this image in xaml.

I have another winui 3 project (Project B) from where I'm referencing this library and using that control (mycontrol)

```
<Image x:Name="myXAMLImageElement"
       Source="ms-appx:///Assets/logo-256.png"/>
```

nothing gets displayed

I tryed :

```
Source="ms-appx://Assets/logo-256.png"
Source="/Assets/logo-256.png"
Source="Assets/logo-256.png"
```

also doesn't work

If I add this image in the Assets folder of Project B then it gets displayed but I want the image to be included in Project A because it is where it belongs.

How do I do that ?
Thank you.

update: I forgot to mention that the build action for the image is set to Content

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines to your `.csproj` file:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Assets\**\*.*" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Here, the `**` indicates to include all subdirectories, and the `*.*` indicates that all files should be included.

Comment: I tried it, it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm concerned, you couldn't reference the Assets folder from Project A in Project B. You need include this image in the Assets folder of Project B.

For more details about reference an image you could refer to the Doc:

[Reference an image or other asset from XAML markup and code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/images-tailored-for-scale-theme-contrast#reference-an-image-or-other-asset-from-xaml-markup-and-code)

Comment: the image belongs to the control created in the Project A library. it should be packaged with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add it as an embedded resource rather than a file. Or expose a method in  Project A that Project B can call.

Comment: that doesn't work either

Comment: Does a method that returns an Image object work?